# Angular-CLI: where is the system-config.js

Tags: angular, angular-cli

When I initialize an Angular-cli project I don't have a *systemjs.config.ts* file.

In many angular plugins it's mentioned to adapt the *systemjs.config.ts*. Example instruction:

> and add these lines to systemjs.config.js:

```
var map = {
    'angular2-tree-component':    'node_modules/angular2-tree-component',
    'lodash':                     'node_modules/lodash',
  };

  var packages = {
    'angular2-tree-component'   : { main: 'dist/angular2-tree-component.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'lodash'                    : { main: 'lodash.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
  };
```

So where is the systemjs.config.js?

This is a standard angular-cli 
create README.md

```
  create src/app/app.component.css
  create src/app/app.component.html
  create src/app/app.component.spec.ts
  create src/app/app.component.ts
  create src/app/app.module.ts
  create src/app/index.ts
  create src/app/shared/index.ts
  create src/environments/environment.prod.ts
  create src/environments/environment.ts
  create src/favicon.ico
  create src/index.html
  create src/main.ts
  create src/polyfills.ts
  create src/styles.css
  create src/test.ts
  create src/tsconfig.json
  create src/typings.d.ts
  create angular-cli.json
  create e2e/app.e2e-spec.ts
  create e2e/app.po.ts
  create e2e/tsconfig.json
  create .gitignore
  create karma.conf.js
  create package.json
  create protractor.conf.js
  create tslint.json
```

Comment: There is no `system-config.js` anymore because cli now build around webpack rather than System.js (hooray!)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

What version of angular-cli are you using? Since `1.0.0-beta.11-webpack` they moved the build system from SystemJS to Webpack. You can find this information in the [changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md).

Comment: Thx. This help me too. But I didn't understand if a tutorial says that I have to add something to that file, what should I do.  For example, adding angular2 material references. Any ideas?